# Iterate over PySpark dataframe and get value based on condition

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, iteration, lookup

I am reasonably new to using PySpark and have the following problem.

Suppose we have the following table, in reality it would have several thousand rows:

```
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
|   ID|       CODE |       TYP|       KIND|
+-----+------------+----------+-----------+
|10087|       BH   |         L|       D   |
|10066|       BS   |         B|       null|
|10094|       BL   |         L|       E   |
|10080|       BF   |         B|       null|
```

What I am trying to do is to iterate over the dataframe. Specifically I am looking at the TYP and KIND columns and based a condition such as if we have a row where TYP == L and KIND == D I need to get the ID value corresponding to the row and look up this ID value in another dataframe for further processing.
My questions is how I best go about this problem, ideally utilizing the parallelization offered by PySpark.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like you could filter on `TYP` & `KIND` columns and join the `ID` column in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
    (10087, "BH", "L", "D"),
    (10066, "BS", "B", "null"),
    (10094, "BL", "L", "E"),
    (10080, "BF", "B", "null")
     ]

df1Columns = ["ID","CODE","TYP","KIND"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

print("df1 dataframe")
df1.show(truncate=False)

filtered_df1 = df1.filter( (F.col("TYP") == "L") & (F.col("KIND") == "D")).select(F.col("ID"))

print("filtered_df1 dataframe")
filtered_df1.show(truncate=False)
```

Then you can join on the filtered dataframe.

Output of the above code :

```
df1 dataframe
+-----+----+---+----+
|ID   |CODE|TYP|KIND|
+-----+----+---+----+
|10087|BH  |L  |D   |
|10066|BS  |B  |null|
|10094|BL  |L  |E   |
|10080|BF  |B  |null|
+-----+----+---+----+

filtered_df1 dataframe
+-----+
|ID   |
+-----+
|10087|
+-----+
```